# Can an Outlook addin write to the system event log?

Tags: c#, security, outlook, vsto, event-log

I have an outlook add-in developed with VSTO 2010 that I want to write some event logging. While debugging I can get this to work by simply doing the following:

```
if (!EventLog.SourceExists(ADDIN_FRIENDLY_NAME))
{
    EventLog.CreateEventSource(ADDIN_FRIENDLY_NAME, null);
}
EventLog.WriteEntry(ADDIN_FRIENDLY_NAME, message, EventLogEntryType.Warning);
```

The problem is the release version the add-in doesn't have admin rights to read the log. I found some articles that talked about creating the EventLog source during installation,  but I'm using ClickOnce and it doesn't seem there is a way to do that. Also, someone talked about creating a separate DLL and then call `InstallUtil` on that DLL to create the source. This doesn't work for me either since this still requires admin rights.

Is it possible to have the add-in run using Outlook's security level? I see Outlook's messages in the event log so it must have enough rights to do so.

Comment: You can't create an event source without admin rights. So, you need to change your strategy and write to something else.

Comment: Thanks John, I did think of that as an option but wanted to check if it was possible to run the add-in at the same security level as Outlook. I can always resort to normal file logging.

Comment: You could always try logging to a remote database - this makes aggregate reporting much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to run click once as administrator using the solution proposed in [this article](http://antscode.blogspot.com.au/2011/02/running-clickonce-application-as.html) but I don't think it's a good solution.

Maybe a better solution is to include in your click once package a standard .msi setup that you can execute the first time you install your addin. This msi just create the event source.

About your question:

> Is it possible to have the add-in run using Outlook's security level?

I don't think that your add-in run using a different security level but probably you have UAC enabled so you cannot execute admin operations also if you are an administrator.

Comment: Marking as answer since it did do so for my question. As for the solution I ended up doing, I wrote separate code to write to a text log file under current user's documents folder instead for simplicity.